# Solaris 10: winbind can't connect to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, samba, solaris, winbind, nss

Goal: join a Solaris 10 machine to an existing Active Directory.

Steps I did:

1. Installed software (Samba 3.4.2 from http://www.sunfreeware.com)
2. Received a Kerberos ticket with `kinit admin-user@KERB.EXAMPLE.ORG`
3. Join domain: `net ads join -U admin-user`
4. Start Samba and winbind

All steps are ok, checked this with `klist`, `net getdomainsid`
, `wbinfo -g` and `wbinfo -u`.

Now the problem: `getent passwd EXAMPLE+username` returns nothing at all (on another Solaris 10 machine this works). Everytime I request somehing from AD, this shows up in log.winbind:

```
[2010/09/07 10:51:41,  0] winbindd/winbindd.c:750(request_len_recv)
  request_len_recv: Invalid request size received: 2088 (expected 2096)
```

According to google, I should [ensure the version of libnss_winbind.so running does match the version of  winbind that is running](http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2007-December/136816.html).

**But how do I do that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solaris 10 ships with a working (if not up-to-date) version of samba however the libraries are not compatible with the sunfreeware product.

The problem you are seeing is caused by the sunfreeware product not having an `nss_winbind.so` library in the package and `/usr/lib/nss_winbind.so` is not compatible.

To fix you will have to create your own. Download the [**samba source**](http://www.sunfreeware.com/SOURCES/samba-3.6.4.tar.gz.) from sunfreeware and unpack it to a convenient directory then cd to it (samba-3.4.2 is current)

```
cd source3
./configure
make nss_modules
```

this will produce a

`../nsswitch/libnss_winbind.so`

On my test system copying this file to

`/usr/local/samba/lib/nss_winbind.so.1`

fixed the problem.

Comment: This works, many thanks! Great explanation too, somehow I lost myself after days of try & error.

Answer (score 1):

probably pam_winbind.so is the wrong version.
look this link: 
http://www.mentby.com/adrian-graham/samba-334-31-sshwinbind-login-failure.html
fix your problem. The winbind.so

Comment: Hi, I only found pam_winbind.so in the `/usr/local/samba/lib/security` directory. So i copied this to `/usr/lib/security`. After a restart of smbd, nmbd and winbind I get other errors: 

[2010/09/08 08:43:38,  3] winbindd/winbindd_misc.c:787(winbindd_priv_pipe_dir)
  [ 8182]: request location of privileged pipe
[2010/09/08 08:43:38,  2] winbindd/winbindd.c:878(remove_client)
  final write to client failed: Broken pipe
[2010/09/08 08:43:38,  3] winbindd/winbindd_misc.c:127(winbindd_list_ent)
  [ 8182]: list groups